# Search command in elasticsearch interpreter of zeppelin does not work

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-zeppelin

```
Zeppelin Version 0.9.0

Elasticsearch version 7.7.0
```

Trying to use elasticsearch in Zeppelin notebook. 
Index, Get or Delete command successful, but  Search and Count command results with error.

Notebook command:

```
search / { "query": { "match_all": { } } }
```

Result message:

```
> Error : JSONObject["total"] is not a long.
```

Same error for Count command. Even if use search/count example from [zeppelin.apache.org/docs](http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs)

Screenshot:[zeppelin notebook with command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GI7fX.png)

Comment: welcome to SOF ! please add screenshot of what you tried . not able to picture your request

Comment: Added screenshot

Comment: did you try  `search /iiii { "query": { "match_all": { } } }` ?? and does the search work if you try from postman ??

Comment: Search/count work from postman. Request  search /iiii { "query": { "match_all": { } } }  in zeppelin also return error

Comment: if it is working on Postman and not on Zeppelin, then its an issue on Zeppelin side - which i dont have knowledge of. sorry .

Comment: Please file a JIRA for apache zeppelin: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN

Comment: @AlexOtt filed a JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-4843

Comment: Yep, I saw it, and put into TODO list